# How to all actions under a controller as resource in Zend Acl

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to follow a tutorial for Zend Auth and Zend Acl using 1.11 framework [Link here](http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/20/zend-authentication-and-authorization-tutorial-with-zend_auth-and-zend_acl/)!

I have setup the authentication successfully and am able to use the authentication for the controller::action pairs given in the Acl.php page. Firstly I would like to test two additional parameter on the users table that whether the user account is activated and if the user is banned by administrator before allowing access to the site. How do I implement that in this code.

Secondly I would like to know how to include all actions under one controller to a User authorization level. i.e. I have a masters controller which has numerous actions under it for various tables. Could you tell me how to restrict access to Masters controller all actions to admin role only. Without adding resources and allow resources for each action in Acl.php. Also please tell me if this logic can be extended to allow access over entire modules instead of just the controllers(by one add resource and allow resource)? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly I would like to test two additional parameter on the users
>   table that whether the user account is activated and if the user is
>   banned by administrator before allowing access to the site.

The tutorial code uses a vanilla version of `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` which uses a specific api for authentication. To make Zend_Auth work how you want it to is not very difficult but will require some thought as you'll need to implement `Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface`. Sounds worse then it is, you only have to implement the `authenticate()` method. Here is an example of an auth adapter that can be used in place of `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable`:

```
<?php
//some code truncated for length and relevance
class My_Auth_Adapter implements Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface
{

    protected $identity = null;

    protected $credential = null;

    protected $usersMapper = null;


    public function __construct($username, $password, My_Model_Mapper_Abstract $userMapper = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($userMapper)) {
            $this->setMapper($userMapper);
        } else {
            $this->usersMapper = new Users_Model_Mapper_User();
        }
        $this->setIdentity($username);
        $this->setCredential($password);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Zend_Auth_Result
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        // Fetch user information according to username
        $user = $this->getUserObject();

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return new Zend_Auth_Result(
                    Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND,
                    $this->getIdentity(),
                    array('Invalid username')
            );
        }
        // check whether or not the hash matches
        $check = Password::comparePassword($this->getCredential(), $user->password);
        if (!$check) {
            return new Zend_Auth_Result(
                    Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID,
                    $this->getIdentity(),
                    array('Incorrect password')
            );
        }
        // Success!
        return new Zend_Auth_Result(
                Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS,
                $this->getIdentity(),
                array()
        );
    }


   // public function setIdentity($userName)

   // public function setCredential($password)

   // public function setMapper($mapper)


    /**
     * @return object
     */
    private function getUserObject()
    {
        return $this->getMapper()->findOneByColumn('username', $this->getIdentity());
    }

    /**
     * @return object
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        $object = $this->getUserObject();
        $array = array(
            'id'   => $object->id,
            'username' => $object->username,
            'role' => $object->getRoleId()
        );
        return (object) $array;
    }
   // public function getIdentity()

   //  public function getCredential()

   // public function getMapper()

}
```

You can modify the auth adapter to do pretty much anything you need.

As far as your access list is concerned, the thing to remember is that you resources are defined by a string. In the case of this tutorial a resource is defined as:

```
$this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('error::error'));
```

where the string on the left side of the colon represents the controller and the string on the right side of the colon represents the action. it's this line in the acl plugin that tell's us what the resources are:

```
if(!$acl->isAllowed($user->role, $request->getControllerName() . '::' . $request->getActionName()))
```

you can change this definition of what your resources represent to anything that works for you.

It's very difficult to provide hard and fast rules on how to implement an ACL because it seems that every project needs something different.

Look around the web and you'll find several different implementations of a Zend Framework ACL, some of them can be very complex.

Here is one that might provide some more insight. http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/02/06/zend_acl-part-1-misconceptions-and-simple-acls/

good luck